# Case When + IN combination

Tags: sql, case

I'm a bit stuck in my coding here... I have this extense and complex code, but I'm actually failling by the end of it. I'm getting the SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type character varying

The thing, is: when "bairro" matches a row from "SUB_COUNTRY_DB", get psd.name, else get z.name. Any tips on how I could accomplish this?

```sql
select distinct
           aa.mes,
           --aa.modalidade,
           --to_date(aa.created_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') data_captacao,
           ucl.ja_comprou_lf as comprou_lf,
           case when bairro in (select sub_country from sub_country_DB)
           then psd.name 
           else z.name 
           end loja,
           count (distinct aa.customer_uid) qtde_socios,
           count (distinct aa.assinatura_uid) qtde_assinaturas
from assinaturas_ativas aa
    left join ultima_compra_loja_fisica ucl           on (aa.customer_uid = ucl.customer_uid
                                                           and aa.mes = ucl.mes)
    left join zip_code z                              on (aa.customer_uid = z.customer_uid
                                                           and aa.mes = z.mes)
    left join SUB_COUNTRY_DB psd 
    on (psd.district = aa.bairro)
group by 1,2,3--,4
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: can your sub_country_DB return null?  giving you `case when bairro in NULL...`?  and, as a matter of form, it's usually better NOT to use the #s in your group by and instead spell out the fields used.  Otherwise someone doing maintaince may inject a new column and screw up your group by..  Lastly what are the data types for bairro & sub_Country?  [Assuming both are varchar or similar)

Comment: No, sub_country_db is never null. Also, both are varchar. I also tried using "exists" operator, but I couldn't make it work either

Comment: I don't see you using any results from "psd" other than your CASE statement so I don't know what joining to psd.district really gets you that joining to sub_country wouldn't. Why not change that LEFT JOIN condition to psd.sub_country = aa.bairro? Then instead of a CASE statement you could just COALESCE(psd.name, z.name) as loja. If any instance of bairro is found with the LEFT JOIN to psd, it will return the matching psd.name, else if not, it will return z.Name.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue/data on a open DB database?  like dbfiddle.uk or similar?  Once it's recreated with data we may be able to play/figure it out.  As it stands, I don't see anything blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try variants like:

- moving condition to an inner query

  ```
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT sub_country FROM sub_country_DB WHERE sub_country = barrio)
  ```
- `ANY` (PostgreSQL only)

  ```
  CASE WHEN bairro = ANY(ARRAY_AGG(select sub_country from sub_country_DB))
  ```